# Get column names as index in multi index data frame

Tags: dataframe, indexing, group-by, multi-index

I have this data frame:

```py
                 Abacate    Abóbora (inclui butternut)  Alface  Alho    
Region  years                                                                                   
PT      1986     NaN            NaN                      NaN    NaN 
        1987     NaN            NaN                      NaN    NaN 
        1988     NaN            NaN                      NaN    NaN 
        1989     NaN            NaN                      NaN    NaN 
        1990     NaN            NaN                      NaN    NaN 
...      ...     ...            ...                      ...    ... 
3       2017     NaN            NaN                      NaN    NaN 
        2018     NaN            NaN                      NaN    NaN 
        2019     50.0           NaN                      NaN    NaN 
        2020     50.0           NaN                      NaN    NaN 
        2021     50.0           NaN                      NaN    NaN 
324 rows × 95 columns
```

How can I do this data frame with 3 indexes ,i.e., how can I pass all the column names as the third index, like this:

```py
                    
Region  years   Products                        Productivity                                                        
PT      1986    Abacate                           NaN
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN
        1987    Abacate                           NaN
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN                                
        1988    Abacate                           NaN
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN                                       
        1989    Abacate                           NaN
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN          
        1990    Abacate                           NaN
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN          
...      ...     ...            ...                      ...    ... 
3       2017    Abacate                           NaN
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN           
        2018    Abacate                           NaN
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN 
        2019    Abacate                           50.0
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN 
        2020    Abacate                           50.0
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN 
        2021    Abacate                           50.0
                Abóbora (inclui butternut)        NaN
                Alface                            NaN
                Alho                              NaN
```

As I have much more columns than the ones I wrote here, I tried doing a "for" function that runs all columns and then grupby with the other indexes but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your expected output image and input data do not match. Please provide correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```py
df = df.stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:"Productivity"})
```

Full example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["PT","1986","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["PT","1987","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["PT","1988","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["PT","1989","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["PT","1990","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["3","2017","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["3","2018","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["3","2019","50.0","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["3","2020","50.0","NaN","NaN","NaN"],["3","2021","50.0","NaN","NaN","NaN"]], columns=["Region","years","Abacate","Abóbora (inclui butternut)","Alface","Alho"])

df = df.groupby(["Region", "years"]).agg(Abacate=("Abacate","sum"), Abóbora=("Abóbora (inclui butternut)","sum"), Alface=("Alface","sum"), Alho=("Alho","sum"))

df = df.rename_axis("Products", axis="columns")

df = df.stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:"Productivity"})
```

Output:

```
                      Productivity
Region years Products             
3      2017  Abacate           NaN
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
       2018  Abacate           NaN
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
       2019  Abacate          50.0
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
       2020  Abacate          50.0
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
       2021  Abacate          50.0
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
PT     1986  Abacate           NaN
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
       1987  Abacate           NaN
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
       1988  Abacate           NaN
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
       1989  Abacate           NaN
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
       1990  Abacate           NaN
             Abóbora           NaN
             Alface            NaN
             Alho              NaN
```